# .NET handlepostrequest - retrieving data

Tags: .net, httphandler

I am sending POST data to .NET simple server example. Among headers I have some other details, which are packed as a input stream into the POST data send. How to retrieve them with HandlePostRequest? My source code is attached here:

```
public void handlePOSTRequest() {

        Console.WriteLine("get post data start");
        int content_len = 0;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        if (this.httpHeaders.ContainsKey("content-length")) {
             content_len = Convert.ToInt32(this.httpHeaders["content-length"]);
             if (content_len > MAX_POST_SIZE) {
                 throw new Exception(
                     String.Format("POST Content-Length({0}) too big for this simple server",
                       content_len));
             }
             byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];

             int to_read = content_len;
             while (to_read > 0) {  
                 Console.WriteLine("starting Read, to_read={0}",to_read);
                 int numread = this.inputStream.Read(buf, 0, Math.Min(BUF_SIZE, to_read));

                 Console.WriteLine("read finished, numread={0}", numread);
                 if (numread == 0) {
                     if (to_read == 0) {
                         break;
                     } else {
                         throw new Exception("client disconnected during post");
                     }
                 }
                 to_read -= numread;
                 ms.Write(buf, 0, numread);
             }
             ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Missing content length");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("get post data end");
        srv.handlePOSTRequest(this, new StreamReader(ms));

    }
```

Everything I get is a content_length, but I need to get data from stream. The stream is gathered by  inputStream = new BufferedStream(socket.GetStream()); And in this stream I have a value "registration"="123456789", how to retrieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
string data;
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
{
   data = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Although if all you need is `registration`.

```
var registration = Request["registration"];
```

Everything is basically on `Request` instance which can be accessed from a `Page`, `WebControl`, or `HttpContext.Current.Request`. In the case of a `HttpHandler` the `HttpContext` instance is passed in for you.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    ...
}
```